# Handling selected TreeView items in JavaFX8

Tags: javafx, event-handling, treeview

Hi guys first of allsorry if it is and stupid question. I am quite new in JavaFX development.

**Scenario**
I am building a menu for an app with the TreeView component of JavaFX8

**Problem description**
The problem is that when the selected item is selected again, the handler is not fired. ie: If i select CHILD 1.1, doSomething() is fired. But if it is selected again without selecting other TreeItem previously doSomething() is not fired. The code looks like this:

```
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("ROOT");
    root.setExpanded(true);

    TreeItem<String> child1 = new TreeItem<>("CHILD 1");
    child1.setExpanded(true);
    TreeItem<String> child2 = new TreeItem<>("CHILD 2");        
    TreeItem<String> child11 = new TreeItem<>("CHILD 1.1");

    tvMenu.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
    String selectedItem =v.getValue().getValue();        
    if (selectedItem.equals("CHILD 1.1")){          
        doSomething();          
    }
```

How could I deal with this problem?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 03/10/2017**

Thanks to **@James_D** the problem was resolved here:

[How do I make a mouse click event be acknowledged by a TreeItem in a TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894108/how-do-i-make-a-mouse-click-event-be-acknowledged-by-a-treeitem-in-a-treeview)

Comment: You listener listens for *changes* in the selection. If the user clicks on an item that is already selected, it does not change the selection (it remains the same as before). It sounds like you are more interested in some other kind of event, e.g. mouse clicks on the cell, or similar. For that you should use a cell factory and register the appropriate handlers with the cells. See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894108/how-do-i-make-a-mouse-click-event-be-acknowledged-by-a-treeitem-in-a-treeview

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and working solution @James_D. I implemented it to my code and it works pretty well.